# S10 cranks but won’t start

Tags: chevrolet, cranks-wont-run, s10

I’ve got a 1997 S10 that sat for a little over 3 years. I got it running but it had a dead cylinder, figured it was a clogged injector after replacing plugs, wires, cap and rotor. Just replaced the injectors Monday and now the truck won’t start at all, cranks over fine but timing light is telling me there’s no spark just replaced the coil and still nothing. It’s getting fuel and I’ve been through it multiple times to see if I forgot to plug anything back in and everything’s plugged in no blown fuses even checked to see if there were any frayed wires and nothing. Anyone have any ideas on what may be wrong ?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: There are 3 different engines that year S10 Pickup 2WD? Which do you have, 2.2L, 4.3L vin W, 4.3L vin X

Answer (score 0):

This is for the 4.3L vin W or X S10 2WD Pickup, let me know if yours is different.

Also let me know if you get stuck at a step that is not self explanatory, as I cannot easily post all the diagnostic info contained in the charts.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Moab sorry I was in a hurry when I made the post, it’s a 2wd 4.3 vin X

Comment: These charts are good for Vin X also.